# Run one off commands via SSH in Elastic Beanstalk and Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to solve this problem for a while now and can't seem to solve it. There are various scenarios in which I would want to be able to run a custom command on Elastic beanstalk. I want to use this command after the server started (.ebextensions does not work here). E. g.

```
python manage.py send_pending_emails_via_cronjob
```

The problem here is that I'm not able to run any commands without the environment variables set. My app needs e. g. `DJANGO_SECRET_KEY`, `RDS_DB_NAME`... Out of the box, these variables are only available when the server starts up. They are not available when I enter the EC2 instance via `eb ssh` - they are also not present in the virtual python environment on the instance.

**I tried:** finding the file that contains the variables at `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/env` to source it. But read access to the file is restricted to the `root` user (I haven't yet figured out how to access the server as root) - however, this feels very complicated and like an unintuitive thing to do. I suspect there to be a more elegant solution.

**Did someone solve this already?**

Comment: Could you implement a custom admin API route, with appropriate authentication, in your app server that would trigger the function needed? Then just call that API at the relevant time.

Comment: Yes, I think this would also work. This would solve the most specific of my use cases. But I think in general it would be super awesome to just be able to run basic Django commands from within the server.